# Uncaught Error: declare: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor

Tags: dojo

I'm using the following code:

```js
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/ready", 
    "dijit/registry", 
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojox/mobile/ProgressBar",
    "dojo/parser", 
    "dojox/mobile",
    "dojox/mobile/compat", // For non-webkit browsers (FF, IE)
    "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView"
], function(declare, ready, registry, ListItem, LongListMixin,
    EdgeToEdgeList, domConstruct, ProgressBar) {

    ready(function() {
        console.log("inside init Videos2");
        mainRegistry = registry;
        scrollableListItem = ListItem;
        ..........
```

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: declare: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor.
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the `dojox/mobile/LongListMixin` somewhere to add as a mixin. The problem is that you're not including that module in your `require()` list.

According to your parameters, you want the `LongListMixin` between `dojox/mobile/ListItem` and `dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList`. Add it there so your `require()` becomes:

```js
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/ready", 
    "dijit/registry", 
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dojox/mobile/LongListMixin", // This was missing
    "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojox/mobile/ProgressBar",
    "dojo/parser", 
    "dojox/mobile",
    "dojox/mobile/compat", // For non-webkit browsers (FF, IE)
    "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView"
], function(declare, ready, registry, ListItem, LongListMixin,
    EdgeToEdgeList, domConstruct, ProgressBar) {

    // ...

});
```

If you don't add it, the next parameter in the list (the `dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList`) is being mapped to the `LongListMixin` parameter, causing errors because that isn't really expected.

Answer (score 2):

For me that error meant that a file in my require list was bogus. Meaning that dojo just couldn't work with it.  It was a file I had created.  Once I got that out of there the error went away and I got the results I wanted.